# Android Create Calendar Entry With Reminder Time Not Working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-calendar

I am trying to create a calendar entry with a reminder

```
public void createCalendarEntry(){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
    calIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    calIntent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "TITLE");
    calIntent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "DECRIPTION");
    calIntent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "");     
    calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    calIntent.putExtra(Events.ALL_DAY, true);
    calIntent.putExtra(Events.STATUS, 1);
    calIntent.putExtra(Events.VISIBLE, 0);
    calIntent.putExtra(Events.HAS_ALARM, true);
    calIntent.putExtra(Reminders.EVENT_ID, 1);
    calIntent.putExtra(Events.ALLOWED_REMINDERS, "METHOD_DEFAULT");
    calIntent.putExtra(Reminders.METHOD, Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
    calIntent.putExtra(Reminders.MINUTES, 20);
    startActivity(calIntent);
}
```

**This code opens up a new calendar entry with the details filled in but does not fill in the reminder time. 
The reminder details stay set to default which is 10 minutes - I want to be able to change this value.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to remove this:

```
calIntent.putExtra(Reminders.EVENT_ID, 1);
```

As you are creating an event, whose ID will be set dynamically and you are aligning the Reminder parameter values to EVENT_ID = 1.

Comment: well it still doesn't change default 10 minutes